# Is there any method to create WMTS GetCapabilities response in xml using java libraries?

Tags: wms, java, geotools, wmts, ogc

I am creating WMTS server side. The problem is that I cannot find any solution where I will be able to generate GetCapabilities xml response in java using some libraries like geotools or similar. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You could use, geoserver where WMTS services are a capability of map services published and GetCapabilties xml is built for you. I try not to reinvent the wheel, when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to study the [geowebcache](http://geowebcache.org) sources to see how they do it. But is a pretty simple schema to follow assuming you have implemented the spec correctly.